# How can I make Laravel log files by the hour instead of day?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, monolog

I have a legacy Laravel 5.5 application with the logging set to daily, but it still generates a lot of data and I would prefer it split up by the hour, for eg.:

```
...
laravel-2019-02-15-00.log
laravel-2019-02-15-01.log
laravel-2019-02-15-02.log
...
laravel-2019-02-15-23.log
laravel-2019-02-16-00.log
laravel-2019-02-16-01.log
...
```

It seems the ability to add custom drivers was only introduced in 5.6, so I can't use one of the drivers for a better logging solution (i.e. a NoSQL database or a third party service). Without refactoring too much of this legacy application, I simply want the logs to be split by the hour. Is this possible? How can I achieve it?

I considered an OS-level solution, such as a cron calling a script every hour to rename the log, for eg.

```
$ mv laravel-<year>-<month>-<date>.log laravel-<year>-<month>-<date>-<hour>.log
```

But I would like to know if there is an easier way to do this from within Laravel.

Comment: There is no built-in configuration for this. But you could make your own driver that does this.

Comment: @Jerodev Can you suggest a tutorial or documentation for a custom driver for 5.5?

Comment: With the way Laravel is set up it's probably much easier, quicker and cleaner to just split your files on a cron task